# how to debug JS runtime errors in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

how to debug JS runtime errors in IE8  when the debugger in IE 8 says that "Source code is not available for this location" and callstack says "JScript annonymous function".

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tool bar in IE8.

You could use stackoverflow.com search and fint [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8)

Also, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also, look [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T14tMtX9XpM).

**Additional:** [Is there a better developer toolbar for IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620729/is-there-a-better-developer-toolbar-for-ie8) (so.com post)